# Error about Connecting database in php

Tags: php, mysql

i am doing my code like this

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","floralsupply");
```

and on this **line** browser is **giving** me this **error**
**Warning:**

> mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: The
>   requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found

Comment: Change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` and see if it works.

Comment: thanks thanks buddyy u are such a genius i was trying this thing but i was unable to do this thankssss alotttt

Comment: check your hosts file if you are on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","root","floralsupply");
```

Comment: If that still doesnt work and you are in Windows, Try checking hosts file whether its localhost or 127.0.0.1 is redirected to somewhere else.